# How to save a byte[] as java.sql.Clob?

Tags: java, byte, arrays, clob

I have a file that I get as a `byte[]` and I have to persist it in my entity as Clob.

How to save a `byte[]` as `java.sql.Clob`?

Comment: clob is a _character_ lob; you therefore should not save a byte array in it. Use a blob instead.

Answer (score 1):

To get a `Clob` from `byte[]` on Oracle, you can do

```
private Clob createClob(byte[] data, Connection conn) {
    CLOB clob = null; 

    try { 
        clob = CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

        clob.open(CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);

        OutputStream out = (OutputStream) clob.setAsciiStream(0L);

        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (clob != null && clob.isOpen()) clob.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to close CLOB", e);
        }
    }

    return clob;
}
```

To create a Blob (binary) is almost the same, just replacing *clob* by *blob* and `OutputStream out = (OutputStream) blob.setBinaryStream(0L);`

Comment: @SurajitBiswas: That's not true. You should note a difference between my object `clob` and Oracle's `CLOB` class and its static `createTemporary` method.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getAsciiStream());
```

if you need special encoding or you have some issue try:

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(clob.getCharacterStream(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This one I've found. But I want to perform the reverse operation. Which is from byte[] to java.sql.Clob.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob` can accept array of char and create a serializable Clob object.

You can refer here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialClob.html

`javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob` can accept array of bytes

You can refer here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html